# Most frequently used word(s) in the text in C#, WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display the most frequently used word(s) in my text using C#. I'm using WinForm, VS2012.

The following code works but it displays "I like apples".

I could break word by word in order to make it displays "apples" but that's not efficient...

I'm new to programming so simpler coding (must be in C#) would be great :)

Thank you all in advance~

```
string[] source = { "I like apples.", "I like red apples.", 
                             "I like red apples than green apples." };

            var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            string highestWord = null;
            int highestFreq = 0;

            foreach (string word in source)
            {
                int freq;
                frequencies.TryGetValue(word, out freq);
                freq += 1;

                if (freq > highestFreq)
                {
                    highestFreq = freq;
                    highestWord = word;
                }
                frequencies[word] = freq;
            }

            this.lblFreqWords.Text = highestWord;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because this line is actually iterating over each *sentence*, not over each individual word:

```
foreach (string word in source)  // source is a collection of sentences
```

Without rewriting your entire program, the quickest way to get individual words out of your current collection would probably be to:

- Flatten all the sentences into one long sentence (using `string.join`), then
- Split that by "space" to get individual words: *(and by the "." to get that out of the way)*

Try this:

```
var words = string.Join(" ", source).Split(new[] {' ', '.'});

foreach (var word in words)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the easiest solution! It works great! Thanks Grant :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 string[] source = { "I like apples.", "I like red apples.", 
                             "I like red apples than green apples." };

            var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            string highestWord = null;
            int highestFreq = 0;

            var message = string.Join(" ", source);
            var splichar = new char[] { ' ', '.' };
            var single = message.Split(splichar);
            foreach (var item in single)
            {
                int freq;
                frequencies.TryGetValue(item, out freq);
                freq += 1;

                if (freq > highestFreq)
                {
                    highestFreq = freq;
                    highestWord = item.Trim();
                }
                frequencies[item] = freq;
            }




            this.lblFreqWords.Text = highestWord;
```

Comment: Hi Anik! Thanks for the solution and the time you spent on writing the code! It works great too! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use LINQ. The following line will return an ordered `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` that (theoretically) represents each word and its count of occurrences. You'll need to include some more cases for "special characters," like punctuation. But this is a good start.

```
char[] wordBreaks = new[] { ' ', '.', ',', '\'' };

return source.SelectMany(c => c.Split(wordBreaks))
             .GroupBy(c => c)
             .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(c.Key, c.Count()))
             .OrderByDescending(c => c.Value);
```

Of course, once you've got that, you can grab `thatValue.First().Key` to find the most common word.

Comment: There is also '.' in the string

Comment: Thanks Matthew! and it's a cute pix too :) but I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with Linq but some people told me that Linq is worth to learn but in this occasion, I must use C#.... Linq is def interesting since I'm familiar with SQL query. Thanks again for your time to spend on writing fab code~ :)

Comment: @user3601310 LINQ is actually part of C#, so this would work within your requirements. But regardless, I'm glad you found your answer.

Comment: Right...I thought it was a different language because of different name.... sorry, I'm so ignorant... :(  Thanks again~

Comment: @user3601310 No problem! Yeah, no, LINQ is kind of like a framework within C#. It's a bit more fundamental than that because there are some language features to support it, but that's pretty much it. It's just a quick way of doing data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

[Grant Winney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813058/80274) goes in to the *why* your program does not work, however there is a even better way to split out the words then just splitting on spaces and periods. Regex has the symbol `\b` which represents a "word boundary", it also has `\w` which can mean any letter a-z, 0-9, and underscore. So if you use the pattern `\b\w+\b` that would mean "A word boundary followed by 1 or more alpha numeric characters followed by a word boundary".

```
    string[] source = { "I like apples.", "I like red apples.", 
                             "I like red apples than green apples.", 
                             "red red red apples, Yum!" };

    var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    int highestFreq = 0;

    var combinedString = string.Join(" ", source);
    var matches = Regex.Matches(combinedString, @"\b\w+\b");
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var word = match.Value;

        int freq;
        frequencies.TryGetValue(word, out freq);
        freq += 1;

        if (freq > highestFreq)
        {
            highestFreq = freq;
        }
        frequencies[word] = freq;
    }
    //This will hold a list of all the words that match 
    var highestWords = frequencies.Where(x=>x.Value == highestFreq).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Highest freq: {0}", highestFreq);
    foreach(var word in highestWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

[<kbd>Run Code</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F7o7j9)

This will strip out that `.` in your sentence. If you want hypenated words to show up as one word instead of two you need to change the pattern to `\b[\w-]+\b`

Comment: Thanks Scott! Great tip! but may I add one more thing? What if the most frequently used word is more than 2? For example I have two words that appeared four times. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3601310 get rid of `highestWord = word;` then after the foreach loop do `var highestWords = frequencies.Where(x=>x.Value == highestFreq).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList()`. That will give you a `List<String>` of all the words that have a frequency equal to `highestFreq`

Comment: Thanks again but I put your DO code right above label but it returns nothing... I think I'm doing wrong, maybe I need to creat List or something(sorry I'm very new...) but thanks for your great help~ :)

Comment: @user3601310 I updated my post with a fully working  example, added a new sentence so `red` and `apples` are tied for 5 uses, and added a button to take you to a running copy of the code.

Comment: One thing you may want to change (and you should ask a new question if you can't figure out how) but make your dictionary case insensitive. Currently this (and every other solution on this page) will treat `Apples` and `apples` as two different words.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for the solution and the little button which I've nerve seen it before! Right, I didn't even think of case insensitive thing... I should probably search it. Thanks for everything~ :)